# Are tabs with their own sidebars and mainPanels possible in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to display different inputs for different tabs. So I tried to build a page with several tabPanels. However, I can't have sth like below:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Header"),

  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(
      headerPanel("Tab 1"),
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("var", "Parametre", choices = c("1", "2", "3"))
        ),
      mainPanel(
        textOutput("text1")
        )
      ),
    tabPanel(
      headerPanel("Tab 2"),
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("var", "Parametre", choices = c("21", "22", "23"))
      ),
      mainPanel(
        textOutput("text2")
      )
    )
    )
  ))
```

I suspect that the `pageWithSidebar` is causing the problem, but I couldn't find an alternative in google groups. Is there a way to display several tabs with their own sidebars and mainPanels, or shall I create different apps for this purpose?

Comment: Please add your dataframe to the question.

Comment: @barerd make a toy example dataframe that illustrates your problem. e.g. something *simillar* to `data.frame( ID = seq(10) , Yas = runif(10) , Hosp = rep( c("A","B" ) , 5 ) )`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If I do not misunderstand your question, I think you can even evade the jQuery part (from @f1r3br4nd answer) by supplying an id for the `tabsetPanel` function, here `id = "conditionedPanels"`. The `value` parameter (i.e. which tab is selected in the main panel) is then available via the `input` variable.

**A minmal example**: `server.R` may be empty except for the shinyServer function skeleton.
The `ui.R` file might be as follows.

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Conditional Panels"),
  sidebarPanel(
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==1",
                     helpText("Content Panel 1")
    ),
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==2",
                     helpText("Content Panel 2")
    ) 
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Panel 1", value=1), 
      tabPanel("Panel 2", value=2)
      , id = "conditionedPanels"
    )
  )
))
```

Comment: You will find more on this here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/07EU9xG11l0

Comment: Could you please explain what the `1` and `2` are supposed to represent?  In practice, my `tabPanel()` commands usually have something like `tabPanel("Panel 2", uiOutput("blah"))`, so perhaps you could expand your answer to include handling common situations like this?

Comment: @warship It is the `value` you choose in `tabPanel`

Comment: I understand, but how is this related to (or rather, how can this be applied to) situations like `tabPanel("Panel 2", uiOutput("blah"))` or `tabPanel("Panel 2", plotOutput("blah2"))`?  I'm having a hard time adapting your code above to situations like this because I don't use `value=`.

Comment: @warship For the above approach to work, you *must* supply the `value` argument... Otherwise you have to somehow solve this using jQuery as done in the other answer.

Answer (score 10):

I got mine to work by having only one `sidebarPanel` like in the Shiny example apps but then wrapping stuff in the `sidebarPanel` that's only for specific tabs in separate `conditionalPanel` calls as [here](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#dynamic-ui). The trick is then to make the character string that is `conditionalPanel`'s condition argument be a jQuery statement that looks at the `html` attribute of the currently selected tab and `===`s it to the name of the tab for which this content should appear in the sidebar:

```
conditionalPanel(
    "$('li.active a').first().html()==='Foo'",
    actionButton("bar","Bar"));
```

...where `Foo` is the title of the tab.

In short, one sidebar but its content conditional on active tab.

Comment: Thank you for this and some other answers about R, which I read via your profile.

Comment: Although I like this solution, I think the supported solution is that by @mark-heckmann.  See his solution in this thread and his link to the google groups in the comment. I would recommend to the OP that he accept his response as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but I stumbled across it when I was looking for an answer to a similar question. I think you can also accomplish what you want by using a `fluidPage` (instead of `pageWithSidebar`) and then using the `sidebarLayout` function in each of the `tabPanels`.

An example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Header"),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel('Tab 1',
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 selectInput("var", "Parametre", choices = c("1", "2", "3"))
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 textOutput("text1")
               )
             )  
    ),
    tabPanel('Tab 2',
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 selectInput("var", "Parametre", choices = c("21", "22", "23"))
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 textOutput("text2")
               )
             )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```