# How do I make dynamic shiny tabs with their own content?

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

So I've looked at the following links to make dynamic tabs when I perform an action and to create tabs with their own sidebars, but I can't seem to put 2 and 2 together.

[R Shiny - add tabPanel to tabsetPanel dynamically (with the use of renderUI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470426/r-shiny-add-tabpanel-to-tabsetpanel-dynamicaly-with-the-use-of-renderui)

[Are tabs with their own sidebars and mainPanels possible in shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225260/are-tabs-with-their-own-sidebars-and-mainpanels-possible-in-shiny)

Does anyone know how to access the tabs after you dynamically create them? Also, is the renderUI example bad in this case because it creates a new list of headers with every action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to thank all the good people over at stackoverflow for aiding me in solving this problem; this is the most supportive site for programming beginners out there.

UI:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(navbarPage("TiGr",

               tabPanel("File Input Page",
                        fluidPage("Input")),

               tabPanel("Summary Statistics and Plots",
                        fluidPage("Statistics")),

               tabPanel("Time Clusters",
                        fluidPage("cluster"),
                        actionButton("subClust", label = "Create Subcluster"),
                        uiOutput("tabs"),
                        conditionalPanel(condition="input.level==1",
                                         helpText("test work plz")
                        ), 
                        conditionalPanel(condition="input.level==5",
                                         helpText("hohoho")
                        )
               )
))
```

Server:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  output$tabs=renderUI({

Tabs<-as.list(rep(0,input$subClust+1))
for (i in 0:length(Tabs)){
  Tabs[i]=lapply(paste("Layer",i,sep=" "),tabPanel,value=i)
}

#Tabs <- lapply(paste("Layer",0:input$subClust,sep=" "), tabPanel)
do.call(tabsetPanel,c(Tabs,id="level"))
})
}
)
```

Comment: under the time clusters tab, you can click to make more sub tabs and on the first and fifth one you'll get my custom messages